# Конкатенация данных в при группировке в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравия желаю, коллеги!

Подскажите, имеется ли возможность (и как это можно исполнить) сложить (конкатенировать) значения ячеек из разных строк при группировке?

Пример таблицы:

```
id | value

zz | aaaaa
zz | bbbbb
xx | ccccc
xx | ddddd
```

В результате запроса имею желание получить две строки типа (например):

```
zz | aaaaa bbbbb
xx | ccccc ddddd
```

Благодарю за подсказки!

Comment: [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Как все элементарно... аж стыдно... Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Агрегация описана в соответствующей документации:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Akina, спасибо!